# android studio gradle sync issues help plz

Tags: android, kotlin, build.gradle

I tried to import the project written around 2016, but the error occurred as below How do you solve these problems?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/57bvn.png)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
            }

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.31'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}



allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

This is my build.gradle

(https://github.com/udacity/ud839_Miwok/issues/143)
I tried the solution provided by the above site, but the problem was not solved Did I find the wrong solution?

Comment: `7.31` -> `7.3.1`

Answer (score 0):

Jcenter() is at the end of its life

add  `maven {url"https://jitpack.io"}` below the jcenter() line.
However some additional tips.

1. Bump up the Gradle plugin to max 4.2.2 and the Gradle version to 6.9.2.

2.There might be outdated libraries which you'll have to update in build.gradle

Comment: A program that wasn't running has been executed Thank you.